# AWS RDS Security Rule to Permit Inbound Traffic From Domain Hosted Elsewhere?

Tags: database, postgresql, security, authentication, amazon-ec2

I have a postgres database hosted on AWS RDS. I'd like to be able to access it from a domain hosted elsewhere. What's the correct way to set up my inbound security rules on AWS? Do I have to permit inbound traffic from all IP addresses (ip == 0.0.0.0), and rely on username/password for security?

Comment: Define elsewhere. It's always a bad idea to open a db up to 0.0.0.0. You need to restrict access from the db end to allow just your ec2 instances / a Nat gateway's ip address your instances use for their outbound internet access.

Comment: The app is hosted on Galaxy. It's a Meteor app that uses Apollo/GraphQL to access a postgres database. What's a correct way to restrict access in a case like this?